# How to use use string function in Angular Interpolation Tag

Tags: angular

How to use string function in Html angular interpolation tags

In component file `somevalues = [1,2,3,4,5]`

Html File:

```
<div *ngFor="let x of somevalues; let i = index">
  {{x}} - {{i}}
  <!-- {{ String.fromCharCode(65 + i) }} -->
</div>
```

I would like to get results somewhat like this:

```
1 - 0 A
2 - 1 B
3 - 2 C
4 - 3 D
5 - 4 E
```

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r2natw)

Comment: I know I could do this by writing a function in `Component` file, but I'm looking make this work in html itself

Comment: In this case, you can not use interpolation (only a few operations are allowed). As you say, the only way is make a function in your .ts, e.g. getChar(value:number){return String.fromCharCode(65+value)} and use as interpolation {{getChar(i)}}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a referecne of the String object in your component like:

```
export class AppComponent  {
 name = 'Angular';
 somevalues = [1,2,3,4,5]
 stringRef = String;
}
```

and then you can use this reference in the template

```
{{ stringRef.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0)+i) }}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use most of the functions from `String`, you could simply create a function in your Component Class:

```
getFromCharCode(index) {
  return String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + index);
}
```

And call it from your Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let x of somevalues; let i = index">
  {{x}} - {{i}}
  {{ getFromCharCode(i) }}
</div>
```

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dyngkq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.